# Is it necessary to have a working second nameserver for an EC2 web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nameserver

I realized that I only had one nameserver configured for an EC2 web server I set up last year, as the other elastic IP didn't get associated. Everything seems to work though?

Is it necessary to have a working second nameserver for an EC2 web server?

Answer (score 1):

Necessary? No. Good idea? Yes.